# How can i scrape javascript code only present b/w two comments by HtmlUnite?

Tags: web-scraping, htmlunit

I'm using htmlunite to **scrape** data from websites.I want to **scrape** the javascript code present b/w two comments as shown in pictures using htmlunite.Answer soon as possible I need it now so badly.[This picture is taken from source page of site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xKYI.png)

Comment: `HTMLUnite` must be `HTMLUnit`, right?

Comment: I'd recommend you to use regex. The comments are pretty unique.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Answer (score 0):

since markers are unique:

`<!-- Start Async Hubspot Analytics Code -->`

`<!-- End Async Hubspot Analytics Code -->`

### Code, *php-stylish*

```
$regex = '/<!--\sStart\sAsync\sHubspot\sAnalytics\sCode\s-->(.*?)<!--\sEnd\sAsync\sHubspot\sAnalytics\sCode\s-->/';    

// and then you try smth. like:
$res = preg_match($regex, $html_page);
```